# Is there a built in function to limit an Int to a Range?

Tags: scala

In Scala, is there and elegant way of limiting a `Int` value to a given `Range`, so that if the value is outside of the `Range` the closest value in the `Range` is returned?

I can write a function to do this, as in the test case below, but suspect that there must be some method on the `Range` class or somewhere else that I have overlooked.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
class RangeTest extends FunSuite {

  test("Range Experiments") {
    val range = 1 to 10

    def limit(n: Int) = (n max range.min) min (range.max) // Yuk!

    assert(1 === limit(-1))
    assert(1 === limit(0))
    for (i <- range)
      assert(i === limit(i))
    assert(10 === limit(11))
    assert(10 === limit(12))
  }

}
```

Comment: BTW: in other languages, this operation is typically called `clamp`, you might want to match your name for that, and maybe also research the APIs of other languages, to match yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid there is none. `Range` is intended as a collection, not as a mathematical value, therefore it provides methods for iteration and likes. Your `limit` function looks good. You might also consider extending ("pimping") the `Range` class:

```
implicit class RangeOps(range: Range) {
  def limit(n: Int) = {
    (n max range.min) min range.max
  }
}

(0 to 10).limit(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should limit n to between 1 and 10

```
def limit(n: Int): n.max(1).min(10)
```